# Rails: How can I define one-to-many relationships using the rails "generate" script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I'd like to run the rails "generate" script and create a model that belongs two other models.  Is there a way that I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out.  If you have a model named "child" that belongs to a model named "mom" and a model named "dad", the syntax is:

```
rails generate model child mom:reference dad:reference
```